# Force linux to drop changes to disk after each reboot

Tags: linux, disk-image

Is it possible to configure a linux system such that the system remembers a certain state of disk image file, and you can also write some changes to the disk while you are on the system, but the next time the sys, all the changes will be dropped ?

Comment: If you refer to a `virtualbox` you can see the [snapshot](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#snapshots) feature.

Answer (score 0):

The [lethe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lethe/files/) package will do this for you. I don't think it's been updated in a while, but [this page](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/07/deep-freeze-like-software-for-ubuntu.html) provides a little guide that might work assuming you're on a debian-based system.

Answer (score 0):

[Unetbootin prepared usb flash](http://www.blores.com/2011/04/how-to-install-ubuntu-1004-with-usb.html) will drop changes. I'm not sure bit probably you can use unetbooin for hard drives as well.